# Create Custom Field type as a separate datatype in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column

I want to create a Custom field type in share point online.It should allow me to create column using that data type.The datatype will be a calculated column and should provide results as Progress bar,stars and others.Whether its possible to do?I don't want to go for JSLink and others as it need to be dynamic one through out the site collection

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint online doesn't support custom field type as [on-premise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms415141(v=office.14).aspx).

You may check [SPFx field customizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer).